# Integer values are being reset to 0 when the sub in which they are assigned values is ended

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

In the following code I have two class scoped variables `intCompanyID` and `intEmployeeID`. When I set them to a value in `btnFetch_Click` then try to read them later in `btnSubmit_Click` they are set to zero.

Why is this?

```
Option Explicit On
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class EmployeeQuestionaire
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim intCompanyID As Integer

Dim intEmployeeID As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub btnFetch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Handles btnFetch.Click

    intEmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtUserID.Text)
    intCompanyID = 1

    msgbox (intEmpoyeeID & " " & intCompanyID)  '  this shows the values
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Handles btnSubmit.Click

    MsgBox(intCompanyID & " " & intEmployeeID) 'shows O O
End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you declare the variables? Locally? Do you have `Option Explicit` enabled?

Comment: You need to show us the code, for us to be able to help you -- otherwise we can only take guesses.

Comment: You really need to post the code but it sounds a little as though you are passing by value instead of by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET will not store **any** state in between trips to the web-server. Therefore, you will need to find somewhere to store your values. You can use the `Session` object:

```
Protected Sub btnFetch_Click
    Session ("MyEmployeeId") = Convert.ToInt32(txtUserID.Text)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click
    intEmployeeID = Session("MyEmployeeId")
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can re-read the `txtUserId` each time:

```
Protected Sub btnFetch_Click
    intEmployeeid = Convert.ToInt32(txtUserID.Text)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click
    intEmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(txtUserID.Text)
End Sub
```

There are many other ways, but ultimately I think you need a much better basic understanding of ASP.NET. It's very different to WinForms programming, or whatever you've used. For one, you *really* shouldn't use `MsgBox` as your code will generally be running on a web-server with no-one to click "OK"!

Answer (score 0):

Every time a page is posted back, the ASP.NET create the page object and generates all the controls and variables you have defined so you need to use [ASP.NET state management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) technique to preserve the state between requests.

For instance,

```
  Protected Sub btnFetch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Handles btnFetch.Click
    int intEmployeeID;
    int.TryParse(txtUserID.Text,out intEmployeeID);
    Session("intCompanyID")=1
    Session("intEmployeeID")=intEmployeeID;
    msgbox (intEmpoyeeID & " " & Session("intCompanyID")) 
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Handles btnSubmit.Click
    If Not IsNothing(Session("intCompanyID")) Then
      MsgBox(Session("intCompanyID) & " " & Session("intEmployeeID")) 
    End If
End Sub
```